# Can we use Agora video call web api sdk in .net core?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I use Agora video call web Api SDK in .net core project?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It seems that the SDK is not supported. For details, you can check its support items:https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/api-ref?platform=All%20Platforms